# nginx location block not directing to location directory when using regex

Tags: regex, nginx

I have a location block that works when I am not using a regex.

```
location ^~ /mapdata/ {
    alias /data/map/coordinates/;
}
```

When i visit `http://localhost/mapdata/2002/g.txt` I am getting the data from the file.

When I alter the location and use a regex. I can not read the file, the location block is correct.  But the url gets an extra slash added on to the end `http://localhost/mapdata/2002/g.txt` changes to `http://localhost/mapdata/2002/g.txt/`

```
location ~ "^/mapdata/([\d]{4})/.*.txt$" {
    alias /data/map/coordinates/;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alias` inside a *regular expression* `location` requires the full path to the file to be captured. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

For example:

```
location ~ "^/mapdata/([\d]{4}/.*\.txt)$" {
    alias /data/map/coordinates/$1;
}
```